# Validar campus chamando função javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

Eu preciso validar os campus telefone e CPF, e para isso encontrei o seguinte script
https://codepen.io/KingRider/pen/qNxror

Porém quando eu jogo aqui no JSF não funciona. Nisso eu abrir uma nova aba do site codepen.io e joguei o mesmo código sem alterar nada e o que aconteceu foi que não funciona também.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vydqjw

Façam o teste.

Alguém sabe dizer o que falta pra funcionar igual??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar o recurso externo [VanillaMasker](https://github.com/vanilla-masker/vanilla-masker)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-masker/1.1.0/vanilla-masker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: eu coloquei e ainda não está funcionando. Eu suspeito que é porque está aparecendo um aviso dizendo que a variável global  VMasker não foi declarada. Como declaro ela??

Answer (score 0):

Faltou adicionares o CDN [**vanilla-masker.min.js**](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-masker/1.1.0/vanilla-masker.min.js), ai sim vai funcionar corretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-masker/1.1.0/vanilla-masker.min.js"></script>
```